# Parse Objects and Arrays in Json data in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to build an array of objects using the data I get from backend service using angularjs. Here is how I get the data

```
"mylist": [

   {

    "name": "Test1",
    "moreInfo": {
    "moreInfoText": "More test",
    },

     "companyInfo": {
      "companyNameInfo": "ABC",
      "url": "http://www.google.com",

        }

        },

        {

   "name": "Test2",
   "moreInfo": {
   "moreInfoText": "More test2",
    },

     "companyInfo": {
    "companyNameInfo": "ABC2",
    "url": "http://www.yahoo.com",
        }


        },

        ]
```

I want to parse it so I can combine it all in one array of objects like

```
[{"name": "Test1", "moreInfoText": "More test","companyNameInfo": "ABC", "url": "http://www.google.com"},{ "name": "Test2", "moreInfoText": "More test2","companyNameInfo": "ABC2", "url": ""}]
```

Comment: What you have in the first place looks exactly like what you want to me. I don't see a difference

Comment: How are you trying to use this?

Comment: The original one has objects within objects. I just want them all in one object.

Comment: Oh, I see that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var flatten = function(object) {
    var newObj = {};

    for (var key in object) {
      var item = object[key];
      if (typeof item !== 'object') {
        newObj[key] = item;
      }

      else {
        var flattened = flatten(item);
        for (var k in flattened) {
          newObj[k] = flattened[k];
        }
      }
    }
    return newObj;
};

var newList = [];
myList.forEach(function(object) {
     newList.push(flatten(object);
});
console.log(newList) //this should be what you want
```

Comment: Here it is on Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/gOsdBMWxBcqr4kj9rD2U?p=preview